# When should I use namespaces in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

In most small projects and tutorials i don't see a use of namespaces, but they are present, for example, everywhere in Laravel framework. My question is: should i use namespaces pretty much always, or there's some sort of "algorithm" to evaluate if I need them or not?

Comment: I would use them in anything that is more than 1 test script.  Get used to them and they become ingrained into your programming mentality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main objective of namespaces is to prevent name collisions, more over they are used to group classes, methods. As you mentioned there are a lot of classes within a Laravel project so namespaces would have to be used to prevent collisions which will happen in big projects.

You can '**nest**' namespaces as you desire, this is usually paired to your folder structure and is relevant if you are using **[PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)** autoloading standard which laravel uses.

For example you may a **User** class (Model) and a **User** class (Repository). Putting them under

> namespace Model

and

> namespace Repository

will make a lot of sense to you, PHP and the autoloader.